# install pip and setuptools on remote machines

Tags: linux, software-installation, python, remote, pip

we want to install pip on all remote machines

on each remote machine we have

```
ls -ltr

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   855608 Oct  7 01:39 setuptools-41.4.0.zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1140573 Oct 20 07:23 pip-8.1.2.tar.gz
```

so the way that we did is like this

```
 ssh $remote_machine "cd /tmp ; tar -xvzf  pip-8.1.2.tar.gz"
 ssh $remote_machine "cd /tmp/pip-8.1.2 ; python setup.py install"
```

actually on each ssh we change folder first to /tmp and then run the command

is it possible to do the same steps without to change folder to /tmp ?

Comment: pip is a de facto standard package-management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python. ... Python 2.7. 9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later include pip (pip3 for Python 3) by default. pip is a recursive acronym for "Pip Installs Packages". - Wkiipedia

Comment: Check Python version with `python -V` or `python3 -V`

Comment: Usually pip is available from the folks who built your distribution of Linux so installing from sources could confuse the built-in packaging system.  Also consider ansible if you want to do a lot of this running stuff on a remote machine via ssh sort of stuff.  It could copy the file for you too.